# How to get Safari Settings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, safari, settings

Is there a way to determine the Safari Settings from Javascript. Specifically, I want to know if the setting Privacy -> Prevent cross-site tracking is turned on. This setting is quite annoying and causes a lot of issues with cookies. If it's on I want to take some action, and if not I want to do something else. Is there anyway to get Safari Settings from Javascript?

I know I can run my code, see if it works and if it doesn't then the setting is probably on. This won't lead to the best user experience though, so just wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: What part of your code isn't working due to this?

Comment: Here is a link to my real issue. It seems that the withCredentials variable doesn't work on Safari if the setting I described above is on. As a temporary workaround I was going to check and see if the setting was on or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225687/ajax-withcredentials-not-passing-along-cookies-in-safari

Comment: Can't you just check to see if the cookies are available or not before running your code?

Comment: How does "*I can run my code, see if it works and if it doesn't then the setting is probably on*" not lead to a good user experience? Is it too slow? Does something unwanted happen? Is it unreliable? It also covers the case where it's not supported. Most browsers allow users to block cookies to some extent.

Comment: So, cookies work if you run the js code on the same domain. There is no issue there. The issue is when you make a cross-domain request and have withCredentials=true then the browser is supposed to send along any cookies set on request's domain. For instance, if a.com sends a request to b.com and b.com has a cookie named access_token, if withCredentials=true then that cookie would show up in the request even though the request is from a.com. But, Safari blocks this with their setting.